# differences between 簡単 and 単純

Tags: word-choice, words, word-usage

簡単{かんたん} and 単純{たんじゅん} seem to both mean simple. Are they used in different situations or have slightly different meanings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite different, actually.

[簡単{かんたん}](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%B0%A1%E5%8D%98) means simple as in "easy", "not difficult", or "plain".

Examples of use would be:

> このゲームは簡単だよ。 This game is easy.
>   簡単に言うと、時間はかかる。　Simply put, this will take time.

[単純{たんじゅん}](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8D%98%E7%B4%94) means simple as in "simple-minded", or "not complex".

Examples of use would be:

> 彼は単純な人。 He is a simple-minded man. (Note this is a belittling statement)
>   単純骨折 simple bone fracture.

For the most part, if you think of 簡単{かんたん} as "easy" and 単純{たんじゅん} as "simple", the meanings should be clearer to you.

Comment: Does 単純{たんじゅん} always have a belittling connotation?

Comment: Only in the sense of calling someone that (if you said someone was "simple-minded" in English, that would be belittling, wouldn't it?). Outside of that, the word itself doesn't carry any negative connotations.

Comment: The meanings of "simple man" and "simple-minded man" are vastly different in English. Simple would mean his motivations are not complex, which could be belittling but is mostly neutral. Simple-minded means he is a stupid man. Which is closer to the connotation that 単純な人 carries?

Comment: @Will Kunkel Just as my translation says: simple-minded. This is the dangers of trying to equate English words 1:1 to other languages. For simple in "simple man", you would use 素朴{そぼく}(http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%B4%A0%E6%9C%B4).